# Codename one - bug when refreshing components of container

Tags: java, containers, codenameone

I do have a list of components that I want to save separately in order to manipulate them isolated from the GUI (e.g. sorting in various ways). 
The components from that list get added to a separate container, which shows those elements in a simple box layout with Y axis orientation.

When I refresh the components in the container (remove all components, add the list again and revalidate or animate the change), I get an index out of bounds exception for the container itself.

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 1
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheckForAdd(ArrayList.java:661)
at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:473)
at com.codename1.ui.Container.insertComponentAtImpl(Container.java:629)
at com.codename1.ui.Container$1.updateState(Container.java:596)
at com.codename1.ui.animations.ComponentAnimation.updateAnimationState(ComponentAnimation.java:95)
at com.codename1.ui.AnimationManager.updateAnimations(AnimationManager.java:69)
at com.codename1.ui.Form.repaintAnimations(Form.java:1373)
at com.codename1.ui.Display.edtLoopImpl(Display.java:1080)
at com.codename1.ui.Display.mainEDTLoop(Display.java:997)
at com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:120)
at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
```

Somehow, when calling removeall followed by an iteration of Container.add(), the internal arraylist keeping track of its components, gets messed up. Anybody knows about this?

```
    private void refreshComponents() {
        container.removeAll();
        container.animateUnlayout(200, 0, null);

        for (Component cmp : sortedComponentList) {
            container.add(cmp);
        }
        container.animateLayout(150);
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks and best regards

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `removeAll` isn't serialized like the `add` operations. Normally when you mutate a state of the container while an animation is in progress the operation is "serialized" so it will occur after the animation is completed.

Please file an issue on that, we'll try to address it. This might be a bit complicated as `removeAll` isn't trivial.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I will try to debug it some more to get more details about the occurance. 
Where exactly would I file that issue, as I have not seen any issue reporting section on the CN1 homepage.